# Selenium Javascript Early Exit (skip to catch, how)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, promise

I'm using https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/wiki/WebDriverJs for my node.js project.

Please take a look at the following code:

```
driver.get(url).then(function() {
   return driver.findElement(By.css('firstSelector'));
}.then(function() {
   # element 1 was found, should early exit
}, function(err) {
   # element 1 was not found, keep going
}).then(function() {
   return driver.findElement(By.css('secondSelector'));
}.then(function() {
   # element 2 was found, should early exit
}, function(err) {
   # element 2 was not found, keep going
}).then(function() {
   # some other big and long function
}).then(function() {
   driver.quit();
   # end
});
```

What I'm trying to do is in case element #1 was found, I want to skip to the end, basically skip over the "big and long function" but execute the driver.quit() part.

Now, I've read a lot about this and what people suggest is the following: issue an error at the point where you want the "skipping" to take place and have some sort of catch at the end that does what you want to do before finishing, in my case 'driver.quit()';

That makes sense, but for some reasons selenium in nodejs won't let me do that. Specifically I've tried this:

```
driver.get(url).then(function() {
   return driver.findElement(By.css('firstSelector'));
}.then(function() {
   # element 1 was found, should early exit
   throw new Error('abort');
   return null;
}, function(err) {
   # element 1 was not found, keep going
}).then(function() {
   return driver.findElement(By.css('secondSelector'));
}.then(function() {
   # element 2 was found, should early exit
}, function(err) {
   # element 2 was not found, keep going
}).then(function() {
   # some other big and long function
}).then(function() {
   driver.quit();
   # end
}).catch(function(err) {
   driver.quit();
});
```

But the catch part is never executed! I've also tried with the following line:

```
webdriver.promise.reject()
```

Again, nothing!

Basically what I'm interested in is - what code do I need to write in order for it to skip past to catch() and call that part?

Thanks!